# In rails, how do you total the values of a hash if the values are nested arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given a hash that looks like this:

```
{
   "one":[ [ 46, 51 ], [ 46 ], [ 48 ] ],
   "two":[ [ 50, 51 ], [ 46, 51 ], [ 46, 51 ] ]
}
```

How do you map this in Rails so that we could get the total number of items in all arrays? So that we would get this result:

```
{
   "one": 4,
   "two": 6
}
```

I'm a little confused with using `map`, because it doesn't let me retain the keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to retain the keys as well

```
hash.map{|key, val| [key, val.flatten.count]}.to_h
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Hash#transform_values`:

```
hash.transform_values { |v| v.flatten.count }
#=> {:one=>4, :two=>6}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can simply use flatten to merge the nested arrays. So if you want to update your existing hash you can do

```
your_hash.each { |key, value| your_hash[key] = value.flatten.count }
```

Otherwise I'd say you do

```
new_hash = {}
your_hash.each { |key, value| new_hash[key] = value.flatten.count }
```